# Update Row in a MySQL Table

Tags: mysql

I have a Table `xt_products`, in these Table I would Update one row "products_option_master_price" with the value "mp" but only the row who has in row "products_master_flag" the value "1"

```
 UPDATE xt_products 
 SET products_option_master_price = 'mp' 
 WHERE `products_master_flag` = 1
```

This won't update all rows, it says 1 record for these query.

Comment: update your question add a proper data sample  .. you actual result and your expected  result ...

Comment: `This won´t update all rows`   but you said there is only one row so what is the problem

Comment: Cool story bruh. Was there a *question*? Or are we just posting a status report? (@scaisEdge: also update the question with an *actual* question)

Comment: When i make this

`SELECT `products_master_flag` FROM `xt_products` WHERE `products_master_flag` = 1`

PHPMyAdmin says 1.387 records found

When i make the update query and say simulation in SQL Browser, he said 1 record found.

Thats the Problem

Comment: @Coobi: the information about the observed behavior should be included in the question, not to a comment. Click on the *edit* button below the question. (For an UPDATE, the MySQL "rows affected" reports the number of rows that were changed, not the number of rows that were matched. To see rows that are "found" but not changed, try `SELECT 1 FROM xt_products WHERE products_master_flag = 1 AND products_option_master_price LIKE 'mp' ;`

Comment: Ok Spencer i will do... But can you tell me who i make the query to update the row that change 1.387 records ?